# AttributeError: 'EasyEnsembleClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit_resample'

Tags: python, imbalanced-data

I am trying to perform a balancing between two classes, one majority and one minority. The majority class is a number of no landslide points and the minority class is landslide. I am trying to apply the Easy Ensemble method to balance the data: I want to have the same number of landslide and no landslide data points.

This is the function:

```
from imblearn.ensemble import EasyEnsembleClassifier

def eec(X, y,random_state=None, n_estimators=10):
    random_state = random_state if random_state is not None else 42
    n_estimators=10
    eec = EasyEnsembleClassifier(random_state = random_state, n_estimators=10)
    X_res, y_res = eec.fit_resample(X, y)

     ax = y_res.value_counts().plot.pie(autopct='%.1f')
     _ = ax.set_title("EEC Frana result")
    
    return X_res, y_res
```

The error I get is this:

> AttributeError: 'EasyEnsembleClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit_resample'

I tried to update imbalanced-learn or use fit_sample but I have the same problem. How can I solve it?

Comment: Why do you expect that `EasyEnsembleClassifier` has a method `fit_resample`?

Comment: here: https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.ensemble.EasyEnsembleClassifier.html you can find the documentation, the method `fit_resample` just doesn't exist. Maybe you're looking for `imblearn.ensemble.EasyEnsemble`

Comment: You're right. It's because I'm tring to visualize the new variables X,y with the resampled classes by Easy Ensemble memorizing the balanced data in X_res and Y_res. At this moment i don't know how to do it